# how to install tpk in TizenOS from within the device?

Tags: tizen

I have a Tizen app compiled in Tizen Sdk and packaged as a .tpk file. I want to install this on a real device. The device i work with does not have USB OTG and I am not able to connect SDB on Ethernet for some reason. However I am able to copy the .tpk file to the Tizen device with a pen drive. Now my question is how to I install this .tpk?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of Tizen OS do you have? Did you try to click on package in file manager?

Answer (score 1):

```
pkgcmd -i -t tpk -p /path/to/file
```

Comment: It says pkgcmd not found. This is a very rudimentary device with no file manager or any other apps. It just shows a wallpaper I can open a  command prompt and that is all. Any other way?

Comment: a little old but you have to provide path to pkgcmd:   /usr/bin/pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p /path/to/file

Comment: I know its old but hey can we run this command from inside cmake file, I have a rpm which includes a project for this app this get written to device memory, but then I have to separately run this command in shell is there a way we can install while rpm gets installed or during the build process of rpm